# C# Winapp: TextBox is hidden by PictureBox

Tags: c#, winforms, textbox, picturebox

I created a shooting game, but I've got a problem with the end. As the player loses I want to show a message to him. I've tried MessageBox, but that turned up in the center of the screen. I just want a kind of box which says "You lost" in the center of the app. I've got PictureBoxes all over the form and as I display the TextBox it can't bee seen (only parts of it).

Any ideas?

Comment: `BringToFront()` will bring your textbox to the forefront of the controls, otherwise are you showing your messagebox with `MessageBox.Show(this, "message")?`

Comment: Thanks, it works!

Otherwise I did it this way:
TextBox tb = new TextBox();
 tb.Text = "You lost";
 Controls.Add(tb);

//tb.BringToFront();

Comment: Cool :) I'll add it as an answer :) I'm always skeptical of bringtofront because some controls fight for the top control

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As I said in my comment, you can use

```
textboxName.BringToFront();
```

to bring a control to the front, if you want a messagebox to appear in the middle,

`MessageBox.Show(this, "message");` should work as I believe messageboxes appear centered on parent by default

**Edit** Just looked it up (MessageBox centering) but it seems you can centre one by hooking but that seems a little overkill

Answer (score 2):

You can create custom form `MessageForm` with label and button on it (classic and win7 screenshots):

[image]
[image]

Settings are (you can set them in designer):

```
FormBorderStyle = FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
ShowIcon = false;
MinimizeBox = false;
MaximizeBox = false;            
StartPosition = FormStartPosition.CenterParent; // important!
btnOK.DialogResult = DialogResult.OK;
lblMessage.Autosize = false;
lblMessage.TextAlign = ContentAlignment.MiddleCenter;
lblMessage.BackColor = SystemColors.ControlLightLight;
lblMessage.Dock = DockStyle.Top;
```

Form class:

```
public partial class MessageForm : Form
{
    public MessageForm(string message)
    {
        InitializeComponent();
        lblMessage.Text = message;
    }

    public static DialogResult Show(string message, string title = "")
    {
        var form = new MessageForm(message);
        form.Text = title;
        return form.ShowDialog();
    }
}
```

Usage:

```
MessageForm.Show("You Lost");
```

Comment: Are you still using...Windows XP? or Windows 95?

Comment: @LarsTech nope :) that is Windows Classic theme for Windows 7 - I like it for simplicity

Comment: @lazyberezovsky I pasted the code that you wrote but is says "The name 'InitializeComponent' does not exist in the current context". And the same for lblMessage. I suppose first I should create lblMessage somewhere, but where?
Sorry if I'm asking an evidence.

Comment: @user2570267  `InitializeComponent` is a method generated by designer when you create new form. You should add new form to your project (from context menu *Add > New Form* with name `MessageForm`. Then in designer put two controls on this form - label with name `lblMessage` and button with name `btnOK` (and play in forms properties in designer). When you will navigate to code of form, you will see class above, which you need to modify.